# Convert YearQtr series to End of the month Date

Tags: r, zoo, yearmonth

I am trying to convert a quarterly series of data in to monthly series in R. I can repeat the same quarterly data for each of the three months in the quarter. Not sure why as.yearmon gives out "Jul" irrespective of Q1,Q2,Q3 etc. Also any help on splitting 1986Q1 in to 1/31/1986, 2/28/1986,3/31/1986 would help. Thanks!

#Input

1986Q1  25

1986Q2  30

#Output

1/31/1986  25

2/28/1986  25

3/31/1986  25

4/30/1986  30

......

#code

```
start=as.yearmon("1986Q1","%YQ")
end=as.yearmon("1986Q2","%YQ")
month=seq(start, end, 1/12)

print(as.yearmon("1986Q1","%YQ"))
"Jul 1986"
```

Comment: Try `start <- as.yearmon(as.yearqtr("1986Q1","%YQ%q"));
end <- as.yearmon(as.yearqtr("1986Q2","%YQ%q"), frac = 1);
as.Date(seq(start, end, by = 1/12), frac = 1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `zoo`

```
library(zoo)
qrtrs = c("1986Q1","1986Q2","1986Q3","1986Q4")
mnths = sapply(1:3, \(i) as.Date(as.yearmon(as.yearqtr(qrtrs)) + i/12) - 1)
sort(as.Date(mnths))
```

output

```
[1] "1986-01-31" "1986-02-28" "1986-03-31" "1986-04-30" "1986-05-31" "1986-06-30" "1986-07-31"
 [8] "1986-08-31" "1986-09-30" "1986-10-31" "1986-11-30" "1986-12-31"
```

This also works for leap years

Comment: Thanks. Getting an error though Error: unexpected input in "mnths = sapply(1:3, \"

Comment: Just ran what's posted here as is without an error. To verify it worked I even started a fresh R session.

Comment: Can it be a version issue? Seems my version cannot take the \(i), is there an alternate way to specify this function inside sapply?

Comment: You can write out `function(i)` instead of the shorthand `\(i)`

Comment: My versions: R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23) and packageVersion("zoo") ‘1.8.10’

Comment: Also `ym <- as.yearmon(as.yearqtr(qrtrs));
as.Date(as.yearmon(rbind(ym, ym+1/12, ym+2/12)), frac = 1)`

Answer (score 2):

Another approach could be using functions from `{lubridate}` package.

Using `lubridate::parse_date_time2` with format specifier `%Y%q` and then with `lubridate::ymd` we can parse `1986Q1` as `1986-01-01`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

parse_date_time2("1986Q1", "%Y%q") %>% 
  ymd() %m+% months(1:3)  %m-% days(1)

#> [1] "1986-01-31" "1986-02-28" "1986-03-31"
```

**Now to apply this for the whole data**

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)


df <- tibble(
  qdate = c("1986Q1", "1986Q2"),
  x = c(25, 50)
)

df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(
    mdate = list(
      parse_date_time2(qdate, "%Y%q") %>% 
        ymd() %m+% months(1:3)  %m-% days(1)
    )
  ) %>% 
  tidyr::unnest(mdate)

#> # A tibble: 6 × 3
#>   qdate      x mdate     
#>   <chr>  <dbl> <date>    
#> 1 1986Q1    25 1986-01-31
#> 2 1986Q1    25 1986-02-28
#> 3 1986Q1    25 1986-03-31
#> 4 1986Q2    50 1986-04-30
#> 5 1986Q2    50 1986-05-31
#> 6 1986Q2    50 1986-06-30
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You could `strsplit` at `"Q"` and use a translation list `q`, which provides months' first of the respective quarter. From this we add one month using `seq.Date` and subtract one (day).

```
q <- list(`1`=sprintf('%02d-01', 1:3), `2`=sprintf('%02d-01', 4:6), 
       `3`=sprintf('%02d-01', 7:9), `4`=sprintf('%02d-01', 10:12))

res <- strsplit(z, 'Q') |>
  lapply(\(x) {
    tmp <- paste(x[1], q[[x[2]]], sep='-')
    sapply(tmp, \(u) as.character(seq.Date(as.Date(u), by='month', length.out=2L)[2] - 1),
           USE.NAMES=FALSE)
    }) |> unlist() |> as.Date()
```

### Gives

```
res
# [1] "1986-01-31" "1986-02-28" "1986-03-31" "1986-04-30" "1986-05-31"
# [6] "1986-06-30" "1986-07-31" "1986-08-31" "1986-09-30" "1986-10-31"
# [11] "1986-11-30" "1986-12-31" "2020-01-31" "2020-02-29" "2020-03-31"
# [16] "2020-04-30" "2020-05-31" "2020-06-30" "2020-07-31" "2020-08-31"
# [21] "2020-09-30" "2020-10-31" "2020-11-30" "2020-12-31"
```

As we can see, the approach also cares for leap years.

---

*Data:*

```
z <- c("1986Q1", "1986Q2", "1986Q3", "1986Q4",
       "2020Q1", "2020Q2", "2020Q3", "2020Q4")
```